# Email based on no entries

Tags: email, google-sheets, report

I know you can set up google sheets so you get email alerts if changes have been made to a sheet but is there a way I can get the opposite?

So, an email daily telling me if no entries have been made?

I need to monitor a form that is not being consistently used.

Thanks

Comment: How about: create a helper sheet and a cell to hold a count of the number of form submissions received; start by manually entering the number of submissions; then a script (driven by a time-driven trigger - once a day) counts the actual number of submissions and compares the total to the helper value; if equal, then send email, if not equal, do nothing; also, update value (setValue) of helper cell with “today’s” total. Rinse and repeat every day.

Comment: Alternative: create helper sheet, create helper checkbox; set value of box to unchecked. When a submission is received, add a line to check the checkbox (that is, set value of checkbox to “checked”). Run script once a day (time-driven), test value of checkbox, if checked then submission received and do nothing; if not checked then no submission received so send email; also last line of script should set checkbox to unchecked. Rinse and repeat daily.